# Matching org tasks against an interval of values

Tags: org-mode

In a list of `files` I have org tasks with the property `E` such that each `E` is marked with an interval range.

```
* Some task1
:PROPERTIES:
:E: [E1, E3]
:END:

* Some task2
:PROPERTIES:
:E: [E4, E7]
:END:
```

...and so forth.

**Question:** How can I `search` through `files` and obtain an agenda view of all tasks that intersect within a range `min` to `max`?

So for example `(search files 3 7)` should display tasks that have, i,e., `[E2, E4]`, `[E4, E5]` or `[E6, E8]` but *not* display tasks have `[E1, E2]` or `[E8, E9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First collect the range of all entries that have an `:E:` property, and then check which of those intersect with the `MIN` to `MAX` range (see `cl-intersection`). Finally, create a regular expression of all entries matched, passing it to the `org-search-view` function.

```el
(defun get-range (min max)
  (cl-loop for range from min to max
           collect range))

(defun search (files min max)
  (let (regexp
        lines
        (org-agenda-files files))
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (when-let* ((el (org-element-at-point))
                   (e (org-element-property :E el))
                   (range (replace-regexp-in-string "[^[:digit:] ]" "" e))
                   (range (mapcar 'string-to-number (split-string range " ")))
                   (range (get-range (cl-first range) (cl-second range)))
                   (line (regexp-quote e)))
         (when (and (cl-intersection range (get-range min max))
                    (not (member line lines)))
           (push line lines)
           (setq regexp (mapconcat #'identity lines "\\|")))))
     nil 'agenda)
    (unless (null lines)
      (org-search-view nil (concat "{" regexp "}")))))
```